# What does "bucking the down draft" mean?

Tags: meaning, phrases, word-usage

> Barrick Gold and Goldcorp were **bucking the down draft** to add 1.9
>   per cent to $15.11 and 1.4 per cent to $14.99, respectively.

What does **bucking the down draft** mean here? If it means decline, then why is it followed by **to add**? Does it mean to add a negative value?

Answer (score 1):

The two gold companies resisted the negative trend posting better than expected earnings:

[Buck:](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/buck)

> [ T ] to oppose or refuse to go along with something:
>   *As a designer, she bucked the trend and succeeded with her own original ideas.* (Cambridge Dictionary)

[Downdraft:](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/downdraft)

> decline, *an economic downdraft.* (M-W)

Answer (score 0):

to **go against the flow**  [TFD](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/flow) and actually gain value.

> To do, think, and/or believe things that are different or contrary to
>   those of the majority of people.